# Specific CLR features

Tags: .net, clr

I'm reading the book "CLR via C#" written by J.Richter, so I have a lot of questions about CLR, which i can't find in book, on forums and so on. So the questions are following:

- **In what time CLR is running?** (when windows loading, when loading first .net app or when)
- **We have separate instances of clr for every .net app?**

  - if not, in what situation we need to have separate clr instance? (in chapter 27 a read this info: "every instance of clr has own thread pool...")
  - if yes, so we have copy of clr for every process?
- **Where can i find clr running, where can i look at it (f.e. Task Manager...)**

Will be very glad for answers.

Comment: Check GutHub CoreCLR repo and learn it's source code. That's the ultimate knowledge base.

Comment: You have the wrong mental model, the CLR is not a separate process.  Just a set of DLLs, clr.dll and clrjit.dll are the important ones.  So every .NET process gets its own and there is very little to look at.  Technically a process can have more than one copy of the CLR but that only happens in an unmanaged program that relies on [ComVisible] plugins or hosts the CLR itself.

Comment: Thanks for answers!